# Different text style while using listSeparatorTextStyleView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles, list-separator

I want to use a list separator in my .xml file, but everytime i do that, the text style changes, it becomes bigger and bolder.

Below are links of the screenshots. The picture on the left is what shows up from my code, and on the right is what i really want.

[Picture for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5WXi.png)

I only want to know how to stop the text from getting bigger and bolder, and at the same time how to put a horizontal line below the `<TextView>`.

Below is the link for the code

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiVR9.png)

Comment: how it becomes bigger and bolder? Show your code to help you.

Comment: yeah, for that only. I've edited the question and added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building from @John Kalimeris' answer, i have a better way, in which no foriegn resource will be needed. This should work for you.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the horizontal line you can use this code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tevi_divide"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="@color/detail_line_divider"
    android:text="@string/str_empty" />
```

you put this below your textview. You change the values of height and margin according to your needs.

Comment: isn't `@color/detail_line_divider` a foriegn resource? How will the OP have that then?